# Checking some mandatory input fields are inputted before resetting the form in JSF + PrimeFaces

Tags: java, javascript, jsf, primefaces

I have a problem in implementing a mechanism for checking the mandatory input fields in the JSF form using PrimeFaces are filled by the user or not before the submission of the form.

I have used *required="true"* mechanism in inputTexts for checking and firing a custom message before submitting for prompting the user to enter some value to the mandatory fields such as this:

```
<p:inputText id="exp" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.dailyCurrencyValues_exp_req_txt}" value="#{marketDataDefinitionProcesses.currencyType.explanation}"/>
```

My boss asked me to reset the page if the user successfully accomplished the submission and stay in the same page. For implementing this, I have used *oncomplete="document.myForm.reset();"* on the submission button which is successfully resetting the form and all the fields in the form.

However, if the user doesn't enter all the mandatory fields and press the submit button, the form is giving a message that is specified in the *requiredMessage*  and resetting the form and all the elements in it. I want to prevent this situation, for resetting the values, if the submission fails. I tried to implement a JavaScript function that is trying to prevent to reset the form if the mandatory fields are not filled. However, again I face a problem regarding to the retrieval of the  element value in my form.

```
<p:calendar id="dateValueId" value="#{marketDataDefinitionProcesses.currencyType.dateValue}" pattern="dd.MM.yyyy" required="true" requiredMessage="#{lang.dailyCurrencyValues_dateValueId_req_txt}"/>
```

I didn't succeed to retrieve the calendar element value by JavaScript.

And now, I am waiting for your opinions in solving this problem. I think, the solutions about retrieving the calendar value using JavaScript or any JSF/PrimeFaces element that retrieves the information about if the *required="true"* field/s are filled or not, are options.

Yours Sincerely...

Faruk

Answer (score 2):

Send a redirect to the same view after post. It will create a brand new request with all input values blank or at least to their defaults as definied in a request/view scoped bean.

```
public String submit() {
    // ...

    return FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewId() + "?faces-redirect=true";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can achieve your goal with PrimeFaces's [RequestContext](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/requestContext.jsf):

```
<h:form id="myForm">
   ...
</h:form>

@ManagedBean
@RequestScoped
public class MrBean {
   public void doSomething() {
      // Do your thing

      RequestContext context = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
      context.execute("document.getElementById("myForm").reset()"); 
   }
}
```

Comment: After creating the context instance, I didn't find the execute pre-defined function. What should I do?

Comment: @FarukPostacioglu I forgot to mention that RequestContext is only available in PrimeFaces v3.0

Comment: RequestContext is also available in the previous versions since I can declare the instance but that functiom's class is not available.

Comment: What do you think I should do for that situation? Is there any way of finding an alternative way to accomplish for resetting the page from backingBean?

Comment: @FarukPostacioglu check if you imported the right package `org.primefaces.context.RequestContext`

Comment: I gave up resetting the view from the backing bean. On the backing Bean side I converted the function for inserting the values to the db to return a boolean value and try to do a ternary condition which is stating if the insertion is accomplished return a true value otherwise return false like                                  actionListener="#{(marketDataDefinitionProcesses.insert) ? alert('true'):alert('false')} "   However, I didn't succeed again.  What will be the wrong side??

Answer (score 0):

maybe you can try to this way

```
 public class MarketDataDefinitionProcesses{
    private CurrencyType currencyType;
    Boolean createStatus;


      public String create(){
         if(service.checkData(currencyType)){
    //insert data
    //show statusMessage or not
    createStatus=Boolean.TRUE;
    reflesh(create,createStatus);
    }
   return null;
    }
    public void reflesh(CurrencyType preNextCreateCurrency,Boolean createStatus){
     preNextCreateCurrency = new CurrencyType();
     this.currencyType = preNextCreateCurrency ;
     RequestContext rc = RequestContext.getCurrentInstance();
     rc.update("form:id"); // if the inputText in the panelGrid, you can put the panelGrid id 
     createStatus = Boolean.FALSE;
    }
    }
```

when the user submit the data , the page need a new instance and use ReuqestContext to update the form or which part you need